Determining a combination of selections from a list of sets that would yield the maximum number of unique numbers
Determining a combination of selections from a list of sets that would yield the maximum number of unique numbers
Consider an array of sets, with each set containing an arbitrary number of integers.
A = {1,2,3}
B = {1,3,4,5,6}
C = {4,5,6,10}
SETS = [A, B, C]

Each set is also given a corresponding arbitrary number that is less than the number of elements in the set. Let’s call it a selection number, or Set_x.
A_x = 1
B_x = 4
C_x = 3
SELECTION_NUMS = [A_x, B_x, C_x]

I need to select Set_x number of any combination of elements from each set (e.g. any 1 element from set A, any 4 elements from set B, etc), such that I can select the most number of unique elements in total. How can this be done in the most efficient way?
E.g. if I choose {1} from A, {1,3,4,5} from B, and {4,5,6} from C, then I would have selected {1,3,4,5,6} in total, or 5 unique elements.
But choosing {2} from A, {1,3,4,5} from B, and {4,6,10} from C gives {1,2,3,4,5,6,10} or 7 unique elements. This is the most number of unique elements obtainable (as calculated by brute force, below) and hence a possible solution to my problem.
(Further extension:
Every integer now has a corresponding property, let’s call it stars, and can be worth anywhere from 1-5 stars. E.g. 1 is worth 5 stars, 2 is worth 3 stars. Set_x would now be the criteria for the total number of stars that can be selected, ie, {1,2} can be selected from a set D whereby D_x = 8.)
Brute force approach:
import itertools
def brute_force(SETS, SELECTION_NUMS):
  NUM_SETS = len(SETS)
  all_perms = list()
  for i in range(NUM_SETS):
    all_perms_per_set = list()
    for perm in itertools.permutations(SETS[i], r=SELECTION_NUMS[i]):
      perm = set(perm)
      all_perms_per_set.append(perm)
    all_perms.append(all_perms_per_set)

  MAX_NUM_ELEMENTS = sum(SELECTION_NUMS)
  most_num_elements = 0
  most_combined_set = set()
  for combination in itertools.product(*all_perms):
    combined_set = set().union(*combination)
    if len(combined_set) > most_num_elements:
      most_num_elements = len(combined_set)
      most_combined_set = combined_set
    if len(combined_set) == MAX_NUM_ELEMENTS:  #all selections are unique
      break

  return most_num_elements, most_combined_set

Some possible ideas I am stuck at:

Count the occurrences of each number, e.g.
count = {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 1}
Then select the element with the least occurrence, remove it from all the sets, and repeat the process. But I cannot be sure if this is completely foolproof, for example, in the case where the least occurring number is found in multiple sets, what criteria do I use to choose which set to select it from?

Changing selections in one set at a time - by making unique selections one set at a time until a conflicting selection arises, in which case we change the selection in one of the conflicting sets. I am unsure if this iterative method would cover all the combinations and reach the most optimal combination; this is also made harder by my inability to determine the theoretical maximum number of unique elements that can be selected.



You almost lost me at "in sorted order" because sets are inherently unordered collections. I tried to go further but gave up half way. There is no programming here just a giant math problem that you don't appear to even have attempted (or at least have no [mcve]). It doesn't really fit with Stack Overflow, I think you would be better asking on the maths site

This seems like a very wordy trivial problem. Sets are unordered, and those look like individual variables instead of an array - never mind that. If you have sets, a union of those sets will give you a set with the unique members of the original sets, and the length of that set will be the number you're after. If you're asking what is the minimum n(S) value given the number values for the sets (which seem arbitrary and unclear - is the actual number of items in each set unknown somehow?), then min(n(S)) is the max of those values. Please state your actual question, and the code it is about.

Thank you for the input. I have corrected some errors and attempted to make my question clearer. Apologies as it is my first time posting and I’m relatively new to coding.

I removed the whole S and n(S) thing because it just made things more confusing. But anyway, I’m looking for the maximum n(S) value; and the number of selections that can be made in each set is given (SELECTION_NUMS). In the case where it is possible to have no repeated selections from multiple sets, then max n(S) = sum of SELECTION_NUMS. However, this may not always be true (seen from the given example above). I am hence looking to find this max number and its corresponding combination of selections.

This can be formulated as a special case of the maximum flow problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem.
The case is applying agents to tasks so that the maximum number of tasks are completed, with a constraint on the number of tasks each agent can be assigned to, less than or equal to the number of tasks the agent is capable of doing.
The tasks are the unique numbers in the set of sets.  In your example 1,2,3,4,5,6,10.
The agents are the the sets ( A, B, C in your example )
An agent is capable of doing any of the tasks in its set, but is limited to the number of tasks specified by the "selection number"
Here is a visual representation of the flow network.  All lines represent a pipe with capacity 1 and flow from left to right only, except for the pipes between the source and the agents which have a capacity of the agent's selection number.

Maximum flow problems can be solved with the Edmonds–Karp algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Thank you, this seems to be the problem and solution I am looking for, will look into it.
